# If we have ∃x[P(x) & x=y], can we conclude P(y)?

Tags: logic

If you can do it, what would be the rule you're invoking? If it can be done, is it like existential instantiation on a term that isn't new since you know x=y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can infer it:

Let $a$ be the witness for the existential:

$P(a) \land a=y$

Then use $\land$ Elimination twice:

$P(a)$

$a=y$

Finally use $=$ Elimination on these two statements:

$P(y)$